Can we say 'limit equals infinity'?
For example, let
$$L=\lim_{x\to \infty} x$$
I would write $L=\infty$.
But is this correct? Should I write it with an arrow instead of the equals sign? It seems wrong to write the equals sign and follow it up with $\infty$.

It's considered to be correct.  We can debate and chew on what it means but it is, for better or worse, acceptable to write $\lim_{\to x} f(x) = \infty$.  I personally prefer to think of it as shorthand for "for any large value of $M$ no matter how large, there is a 'point of no return' $N$ where $f(x) > M$ for all $x > N$".  Others may think of it as "As $f(x)\to \infty$ the limit of $f(x)$ is 'infinitely large' and equal to infinity".  I don't like that way of thinking but I wouldn't go so far as to say it is "wrong".

In calculs context, this is just a notation to say that the sequence or function or series diverges.

@user: While that notation certainly implies that the sequence or function diverges, divergence is strictly more general.

In this context it means that the limit diverges by becoming arbitrarily large. This is a relevant distinction as it means $\lim_{x\to \infty}$ so $\frac1x = 0$. Note that the function $\sin x$ diverges as $x \to \infty$ but is bounded so it doesn't diverge to infinity. It's common practice to add the two tokens $\infty$ and $-\infty$ to the real numbers for the two exceptional types of divergence.

As long as you don't misuse the notation, it's fine.  (This consideration already occurs with the limit forms $1/0$ and $0/0$, so it's not just introducing the symbols $\infty$ and $-\infty$ that causes it)

All it takes to make the notation perfectly fine is to take a couple objects that are not real numbers and label them as $\infty$ and $-\infty$, and assign them as the limits of functions that increase or decrease without bound. Then the notational crisis goes away. You can define the "Extended Reals" by adding them to the reals. but they are, even then, not real numbers, and should never be regarded as such. There is no way to make them obey the same rules all real numbers must obey.
